# How to remove older data and save new data in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my collection looks like

```
[{
   '_id':'1',
   'name':'John',
   'message':'Hi'
},
{
   '_id':'2',
   'name':'John',
   'message':'Hey'
},
{
  '_id':'3',
  'name':'John',
  'message':'Hello'
}]
```

When I save next data, which

```
'_id' will be '4', 'name':'John', 'message':'howdy'.
```

I want to push `'_id':'4'` to collection and pop `'_id':'1'`; similarly, when I save `'_id':'5'` to same collection `'_id':'2'` will remove and so on.

I want to delete older data and save new data of limit entry within a collection.

So how do I write this in `MongoDB` schema?

Answer (score 2):

You can use capped collection for this purpose. An example in the `mongo` shell:

```
db.createCollection('capped', {capped: true, size: 100000, max: 3})
```

will create a capped collection named `capped`, with maximum size of 100000 bytes, and will contain a maximum of 3 documents. The oldest document will be deleted when a new document is inserted.

```
> db.capped.insert({_id: 1, name: 'John', message: 'Hi'})
> db.capped.insert({_id: 2, name: 'John', message: 'Hey'})
> db.capped.insert({_id: 3, name: 'John', message: 'Hello'})

> db.capped.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "John", "message" : "Hi" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "John", "message" : "Hey" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "John", "message" : "Hello" }
```

When you insert a new document:

```
> db.capped.insert({_id: 4, name: 'John', message: 'howdy'})

> db.capped.find()
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "John", "message" : "Hey" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "John", "message" : "Hello" }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "John", "message" : "howdy" }
```

the oldest document is removed from the collection automatically. Similarly:

```
> db.capped.insert({_id: 5, name: 'John', message: 'hello'})

> db.capped.find()
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "John", "message" : "Hello" }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "John", "message" : "howdy" }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "John", "message" : "hello" }
```

Please see the [Capped Collections page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to write any schema, all you need to do a little logic.that is

**count number of collections in and divide _id of new document by the count and assign remainder to it. Now this new _id is where you have to update your document.**

> ```
> count = numberOfDocumentsInCollection
> newDoc._id = newDoc._id%count
> ```

Below is the complete code.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb';

var newDoc = {
  _id:4,
  name:"John",
  message:"this is vajahat"
}
MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
  if(err)
    return console.log(err);
  var collection = db.collection('test');
  collection.count(function(err,count){
    // this is number of documents
    var idToBeUpdatedAt= newDoc._id%count;//<<-------Here is the trick
    delete newDoc._id;
    console.log(idToBeUpdatedAt,count);
    collection.updateOne({"_id":idToBeUpdatedAt},{"$set":newDoc},function(err,updated){
      if(err)
        return console.log(err);
      console.log("updated");
      db.close();
    });
  });
})
```